# How to display book description in MySQL using heidi?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to create a stored procedure in HeidiSQL but I am really having a hard time doing it.

The program I'm trying to create should show the book description when the user enters the book title and clicks the submit button.

Here is my code for the stored procedure and the table I created:

```
BEGIN
select * from books
where 
Title = Description;
END

CREATE TABLE books 
(
    IDBooks INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Title VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    Description VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (IDBooks)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So your SQL returns a list of all books with the title and description equal to each other. So if your books table contains

```
ID    Title                     Description
1     A Tale of Two Cities      A Tale of Two Cities
2     Moby Dick                 A story of captain Ahab and a white whale.
3     Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde   Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde
```

Your query would return

```
ID    Title                     Description
1     A Tale of Two Cities      A Tale of Two Cities
3     Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde   Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde
```

What you need is a function that takes a single Varchar input parameter, let's name it `p_title`, and returns a Varchar. The routine body would look something like this:

```
BEGIN
  Declare result as varchar(50);
  Select description into result
    from books
    where title = p_title;
  Return result;
END
```

You need to guard against multiple books with the same title as that will cause `select into` to fail. You could accomplish that with a unique index on the title.

Comment: hi Jimarkmurphy 
Thank you for taking your time to replying me back .The title and Description are not the same .
lets say the Title is php and description is Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde

Comment: I'm not real sure what your issue is at this point. I realize that the title and description should be different. I was pointing out that, with the SQL you provided, they would have to be the same for a book to be selected. I am not sure why you want to use a stored procedure. HeidiSQL is an SQL client, so it doesn't seem that the users would be using it directly, but that you are probably using it to develop your SQL statements. If you try my SQL, you should provide a title, and it will return the description, whatever it is. Do you know how to call the stored procedure?